# API divided into REST and SOAP parts and design patterns

Tags: design-patterns, api

I need to work with some payment gateway API. The API is divided into two parts. There are some methods based on REST and a few methods accessible through SOAP webservice. I would like to create some bridge to combine it into single API class in my application. However I am not sure it is a good choice.
The question is.. is there any design pattern for this kind of situations?

Comment: What specific problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I think it is.. how to handle a poorly designed API. The API is created by a payment operator in my country so it is a real problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Choosing the right Design Pattern](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/227868/choosing-the-right-design-pattern)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest [Gateway](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/gateway.html)

The difference is that Gateway hides external API complexity to your internal API.

Facade, seems to me the opposite. Hides your complexity to external clients.

In both cases the implementation is similar.

Comment: That does sound like a match.

Comment: By match, Do you mean that both are the same? Could be, depends from the point of view. Gateway also focus on gathering different resources in a single entry point. Independently the quality or complexity of the API hidden behind.

Comment: I meant that it sounds like the Gateway pattern addresses what the original poster asked about, and does so pretty specifically. In practice, a facade for two APIs is not going to be any different from a gateway, but the description of the Gateway pattern seems more specific to OP's original question. Good answer.

Answer (score 2):

As @user1172763 mentioned this is called a [Facade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern). A facade is usually used to provide a simplified interface for a more complex system. But as the wiki link mentions, a Facade is also used to:

> wrap a poorly designed collection of APIs with a single well-designed API.

In this case you hide two heterogenous APIs (one REST, one SOAP)  behind a homogenous (facade) API.

Answer (score 1):

Not much of a pattern nerd, but I think that you would use the "Facade Pattern."

Comment: without an explanation, this answer may become useless in case if someone else posts an opposite opinion. For example, if someone posts a claim like _"I think that you would not use the "Facade Pattern.""_, how would this answer help reader to pick of two opposing opinions? Consider [edit]ing it into a better shape, to meet [answer] guidelines

Answer (score 1):

And in addition to using the Facade pattern, and if you want to get more elegant and pure with your code, I would recommend using the Adapter pattern to cleanly convert the interface of the outer API classes to what is expected for the inner API classes.