# Design for consuming list items for a state machine like structure

Tags: c#, .net, finite-state-machine

I'm trying to improve this document parser and there is one main loop that goes over all of the main elements (let's call them `Node`s). Each step (`Step`) can either `Consume` or `Ignore` the `Node` that it is passed. A `Step` can also be greedy and consume more than the single `Node` than was passed to it. A `Step` could restrict its transition to other states like a state machine. I can't remove `Node` from the list of nodes as that would get me into collection modified while enumerating problems and it would be difficult to accelerate the main loop

What design would work well for this?

Here is something I have been considering to implement.

```
class Node { ... }
class Step 
{
    void Handle(NodeContext);
    ... 
}
class NodeContext
{
     Node Node { get; }
     void Ignore();
     void Consume();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Choosing the right Design Pattern](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/227868/choosing-the-right-design-pattern)

Comment: I don't think this question is about design patterns, so it should be edited to say "design" instead of "design pattern", instead of being closed as a duplicate of the Big Design Pattern Question. I've submitted a proposed edit.

Comment: I would not worry about the class structure as much as the algorithm. In general, you should never modify the list you are iterating, unless you are working from the back to the front, and only delete the last element.

Comment: @gnat: I recommend to reread my answer here and go through the steps I listed there: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8562/9113