# What design pattern to use while designing district?

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented-design

Lets say I am trying to design a district. 
  I have

```
         1) house
         2) community (groups of 2 or more then 2 house)
         3) city (group of more then two community)
         4) district (groups of 2 or more then 2 city)
```

What I have so far :

```
class house{
   public: 
    house(std::string name, std::string id);
    std::string get_name();
    std::string get_id();
  private:
   std::string name;
   std::string id;

};

class community{
   public:
      community();
      // get house names
     std::vector<std::string> get_all_house_in_community();
   private:
     std::string name;
     std::vector<house> p_houses; // vector of house 
};

class city{
   public:
      city();
      // get house names by collecting from communities
      std::vector<std::string> get_all_house_in_city();
   private:
     std::string name;
     std::vector<community> p_communities; // vector of community
}

class district{
   public:
     district();

     // get house names from city
     std::vector<std::string> get_all_house_in_district();
   private:
     std::string name;
      std::vector<city> p_cities; 

};
```

When the get_all_house_in_district() function is called it has to call all the get_all_housexxxx of the classes. Is it a good idea to distribute data among classes this way or should the district hold all the houses(If I let district hold all the houses then the district class gets really complicated really quickly)?

side question : should I use inheritance here, I don't see any reason but was just curious.

With these classes I wanted to create a simple data base system.

Is there any design pattern to represent this scenario?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Choosing the right Design Pattern](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/227868/choosing-the-right-design-pattern)

Answer (score 4):

In general, there are two ways to look at data: logical and physical.  In a database, all your houses would be in one table with foreign keys to figure out what the house belonged to.  However, that's more of a "physical" layout of how data is stored.  It doesn't represent the domain very well.

In Object Oriented Programming, we typically keep the classes behaving as if it were written using the logical model.  Internally, they can use whatever optimizations are deemed appropriate.  It is best to start with everything modeled logically.  You can always change that later.

What you are describing is a compositional hierarchy of data.  It makes sense then to use composition to represent the different types of objects.  If it helps, you can think of the relationships of inheritance and composition like this:

- Inheritance: *is a* relationship (SingleFamilyHouse *is a* House)
- Composition: *has a* relationship, or *contains* relationship (Community *has* Houses)
- Interface (pure virtual class in C++): *acts as* relationship (Joe *acts as* Police)

To be honest, composition provides the most reusable code, but there is a place for each approach.

In this approach you'll have to write the `get_all_houses_in_district` method to call the appropriate methods on it's direct children, and they do the same for their children.

Comment: what do u mean when u say "appropriate methods on it's direct children" is that similar to what I did when I do get_all_house_in_community(); ..

Comment: Right.  You just have to walk down the hierarchy.  For each city you call `get_all_houses_in_community` which in turn will give you the houses to add to your master `std::vector<house>` etc.  Although, you may want to name your methods better.  Either change your `get_all_houses_***` methods to return a vector of houses or change the name to `get_all_house_names_***`.  It's probably safest to work strictly with the house obejcts.