# Representing mathematical tree structures using software in a compact manner

Tags: object-oriented, python, object-oriented-design, functional-programming

In my work I frequently come across systems of interdependent equations. I have contrived a toy example as follows. The terminal values `w`, `x`, `y` and `z` are given:

`e(y) = A+B`

`A(y) = x*log(y)+y^z`

`B(y) = alpha*y`

`alpha(y) = x*y+w`

We could then consider the function `e(y)` as the root of an arithmetic tree with the following heirarchy:

[image]

Previously, in python I would have done something like this to evaluate the result:

```
import numpy as np

def root(B, A):
    return B+A

def A(x,y,z):
    return x*np.log(y)+y**z

def B(alpha, y):
    return alpha*y

def alpha(x,y,w):
    return x*y+w

if __name__=='__main__':

    x,y,z,w = 1,2,3,4
    result = root(B(alpha(x,y,w),y), A(x,y,z))
```

This will give me the right result, but I have come to really despise this way of doing things. It requires me to keep track of which arguments each function needs and how the tree itself is built up. Also, suppose I wanted to modify the tree itself by adding branches and leaves. For example, say I wanted to redefine `alpha` as `v+x+y` with the new variable `v`. I'd have to make a new function and a new call, which is not very efficient as I sometimes need to make pervasive and numerous changes.

I tried different approaches to solve this problem as outlined by [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/399899/seeking-appropriate-design-patterns-to-describe-most-function-based-mathematic) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58354848/seeking-common-ground-between-object-oriented-structures-and-mathematical-logic).

I came across a couple of ideas which looked promising, namely [function objects](http://hplgit.github.io/primer.html/doc/pub/class/._class-readable001.html) and the [Interpreter Pattern](https://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~hv/classes/CS400/01.hchen/doc/interpreter/interpreter.html). However I was disappointed by the Interpreter Pattern. Suppose I didn't create a parser, and went straight for the underlying composite architecture, wouldn't I still have to do something like this?

```
root = root_obj(B_obj(alpha_obj(x_obj,y_obj,w_obj),y_obj), A(x_obj,y_obj,z_obj))
root.interpret()
```

The above would require a lot of added complexity for no added value. My question is as follows: What is a simple and useful object oriented paradigm in which I could **define**, **modify** and **evaluate** a mathematical heirarchy in a dynamic manner?

**EDIT**

Here's an example of what I would like to achieve:

```
tree = FunctionTree()
tree.add_nodes(root, A, B, alpha, w, x, y, z)
tree.add_edge(root, [A, B])
tree.add_edge(root, A)
tree.add_edge(A, [x,y,z])
tree.add_edge(B, [alpha, y])
tree.add_edge(alpha, [x, y, w])
tree.evaluate()
```

Yes, this is less "compact" but it is much more flexible. Imaging having methods for deleting and adding new edges. replacing definitions at nodes and reevaluating the result. I am looking for something like this.

Comment: It really depends on what you mean by "compact". Using Expression object is most common way of representing and evaluating equations. Are those not "compact" enough? Why not? Why not implement a simple parser and represent the equations as simple strings that are then parsed?

Comment: Only mention of "compactness" is in end of last sentence. Nothing else in your question implies any relation to "compactness". Could you provide some pseudo-code how you imagine defining or modifying an expression that you would consider compact?

Comment: Okay. In your representation, where do you put the mathematical operations? Also, how would changing the tree look like after it was created? And where are parameters coming from in evaluate method?

Comment: It could be that the nodes of the trees are function objects which are aware of their own arithmetic and arguments. Arguments can either be terminal or non-terminal. functions which have only terminal arguments are closer to the leaves and functions which have only non-terminal arguments are closer to the root. With regards to changing the tree, it would be a simple matter of replacing a node and redefining the connectivity to terminal/nonterminal arguments.

Comment: Sorry. I'm still not sure what you actually want. When I try to imagine your pseudo code as real code, I don't see it as more simple or "compact" than what could be achieved by expressions or an interpreter.

Comment: forget the word "compact". Think "flexible" instead. I want to be able to define a function tree that knows which functions it contains and how they are interrelated. It also has an evaluate method which will take all terminal arguments  and send them up the heirarchy all the way up to the root to give me a final answer.

Comment: The tree you draw is a simple example of an Abstract Syntax Tree (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), writing a parser that takes a string representing a mathematical expression and construct its Syntax Tree is pretty straightforward. Is this maybe what you are looking for?

Comment: Sorry to insist with what I said on the other question: the design pattern does not require you to parse anything. The inteepreter pattern is just about the execution pattern usign an external context to find the values of determined variables of your equation

Comment: Where do the math functions come from? Are they defined in code or is the end user allowed to modify them?

Comment: @WinstonEwert both. They should be defined in code and open to modification.

Comment: @user32882, wanting to do both is a big red flag. I'd have a better understanding of the whole system to offer any sort of helpful input on it.

Comment: How is it a "big red flag" lol. We do it in mathematics all the time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a continuation of your previous question.  The [recommendation made in this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/399907/209774) is still valid. But maybe I was not clear enough.

I'm not python fluent, but:

- Create a class `AbstractExpression`.
- Create a concrete specialisation class for every specific function you have: `Function_e`, `Function_A`, `Function_B`, `Function_Alpha`.  Instances of these class would correspond to your orange boxes.
- Create a concrete class for the terminal expression.  Call it `Variable`, and imagine that every instance of this class has a name. Instance of this class would correspond to your green circles.
- For clarity, let's use the pattern with a function `eval(context)` instead of `interpret(context)`

Now to the point on which I was not clear enough:

- Of course,  `Function_e`'s constructor would construct a `Function_A` instance called `fA` and a `Function_B` instance. Absolutely no parsing is required here !
- Of course, `Function_A` would create `Variable` instances, `vy` with the names "y", `vz` for "z" and `vx` for "x".   Again, no parsing is needed:  the class constructor construct the needed objects (you code it).
- The `Function_e`'s `eval()` would do what it needs and call `fA.eval()` where  the result of this functions is needed in the formula. I'll insist: absolutely no parsing takes place here! It's your implementation of `e` that will call a method of your implementation of `A`
- in your implementation of `fA.eval()`, you would call `vy.eval()`, `vz.eval()` and `vx.eval()` in the formula, where you would need each of these variables.

Now we have constructed an interpreter corresponding to your system, (without any parsing), and that is able to calculate the result, if only `Variable.eval()` could know the values to be used for these parameters. And here enters the `context`:

- `context` would be a dictionary that assigns fixed values to variable names.
- `context` is forwarded as single parameter through all the `eval()` calls explained above.
- the last implementation needed is `eval()` for `Variable`. This would just return the value associated to the variable's name in the `context` dictionary.

Sorry if I insisted on the absence of parsing.  But many web site provide examples of the interpreter pattern without understanding real use cases.  So they all are about parsing, which creates significant confusion.  You have here a perfect example of use :-)

Comment: One thing Python specific here that could change the answer is that there's a special function [`__call__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__) that (I think) obviates the need to define an `exec` method.  You could then use the root/top level object like any python function.  It could even take parameters but I'm not sure  if that's helpful here or not.

Comment: @Christophe I appreciate your answer, but how would my `main()` method look like with your proposal? Also would I be able to redefine the abstract tree with relative ease? I.e without having to go back into the classes themselves?

Comment: @user32882 The abstract tree is the result of the cascaded construction process described above (so taking place in the `__init__(self)` of the classes).  As said, I'm not python fluent, but your main would look like `root = Function_e()` followed by `context = { "x":1, ....}` followed by `result = root.eval(context)`

Comment: I think you have the right idea and the fact I am not catching on is mainly due to my own ignorance about design patterns. I will continue to look through Interpreter/Composite to learn more. If/when I am able to implement one or both for this use case, I will accept both your answers. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'd say `Composite` and a `Visitor` pattern would be more adequate for what I am trying to achieve. I'll accept your answers though because they have pointed me to the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58571505/evaluating-tree-without-having-to-build-an-interpreter-python