# What design pattern am I up to here?

Tags: design-patterns

I am making a small "search engine app". The app should get three pieces of input from the user:

1. The name of the search engine as a string (e.g. "googe", "duckduckgo", etc)
2. The search term
3. The name of the website the user wants to search on if they want to search only webpages of a particular website (e.g. "reddit.com", "stackoverflow.com", etc)

I am having a `SearchEngine` class for this which I am thinking it would initialize like so:

```
se = SearchEngine(url="https://google.com")
```

However, the user will be entering "google" as input, not the entire https://google.com URL.

Now, I plan to have both a command line and a web interface.

For example, in the CLI the engine **name** would come through an input functon:

```
engine_name = input("Search engine name: ")
```

In a web interface the engine name would come through an HTML input element.

So, the client is sending a `name` while the `SearchEngine` class is getting a `url`. One way to solve that "incompatibility" would it be to initialize a SearchEngine object like below:

```
se = SearchEngine(name="google")
```

and convert the `name` to a `url` inside the `SearchEngine` constructor. I am afraid that would be a bad design.

Would it be better to have another intermediate layer (class?) that converts `name` to a `url`? That way `SearchEngine` would be independent from the user/client input format.

What design pattern am I using here? What design pattern should I use?

Comment: Don't over complicate it it, all you need to convert a name to a URL is a Dictionary, a whole class is serious overkill.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Choosing the right Design Pattern](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/227868/choosing-the-right-design-pattern)

Comment: @Turksarama: the question was not how to implement the mapping, but where to place the implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "What design pattern am I using here?"

**None.**

> "What design pattern should I use?"*

**None**.

Do yourself a favor and stop searching for *reusable* solutions (=patterns) before you haven't build a *usable* solution.

> "Would it be better to have another intermediate layer (class?) that converts name to a url?"

Some piece of code will have to do the conversion, of course. To know where it makes most sense to place the code in your app one has to know the overall structure of the app. Since you are probably still developing this structure, I would recommended the following:

- start with the **most simple** solution for the problem you can come up with. If that is making the search engine name a constructor parameter of your `SearchEngine` object, that's fine. How it will work internally (using a switch statement, two pairwise lists or a dictionary) is an implementation detail you should figure out by yourself.
- when the code base grows and the constructor code becomes "too large" and convoluted, or in case you want to maintain the list of available search engines at a different place, maybe outside of the code at all, then **refactor** your code, extract the conversion to a different class or layer and call that layer from the `SearchEngine` constructor.

TLDR; don't overanalyse beforehand, instead refactor as you go.