# Modify method behaviour at runtime

Tags: architecture, javascript, web-development, factory, strategy-pattern

I have a scenario where user has multiple filters in a web application and a displayed list of items. In the gui it has multiple `FilterGUI` that he/she can tune interacting in the browser (these are React web components).
Every specific implementation of the `FilterGUI` do the same: tune parameters and according to parameters create at runtime an arrow function that will filter (according to some algorithm/criteria) the dataset items.

Example:

i have data like this:

```
user {
    name: "bob",
    age: 25
    }
```

```
FilterGUI1 {
    createFilterFunction() {
         return (userSelectedInterval) => {
                      I filter user by age based on an interval selected by the user
                      }

    }
}
```

```
FilterGUI2 {
     createFilterFunction() {
          return (criteria1, criteria2 ...) => {
          i filter user item based on nested if else criteria  
          }
     }
}
```

It seems to me that `createFilterFunction()` may be replaced by a `FilterFunctionFactory`
such that:

```
FilterGUI {
    this.filterFunctionFactory = new FilterFunctionFactory()

    makeFilter(someParams) {
        return this.filterFunctionFactory.makeFilter(someParams)
    }
}
```

I read also something about Strategy pattern. In particular that it *allows selection of an algorithm’s behaviour during runtime.* Can this pattern be used somehow here to modify the `filterFunction` produced by the factory at runtime?
How would you do that ?
I'm not an expert on software design patterns by i would like to write this code in a much elegant way.

**UPDATE**

After @BartvanIngenSchenau pointing to great article on how choosing design pattern I try to reformulate the question. Possibly avoiding to make it appear less "how to combine design patterns to write code".

I have different web components all implementing `FilterGUI` interface. For example `FilterByAgeGUI`, `FilterByPriceGUI` ...

```
interface FilterGUI {
    makeFilter(someFilterCrieria) : IFilter
}
```

```
interface IFilter {
    someFilterCriteria
    filter(someFilterCriteria, datasetNode) : boolean
}
```

`filter` method should accept `someCriteria` provided at runtime by `FilterGUI` and a `datasetNode`, and decide based on criteria if keeping node or not.

My question is: is there a way to have a general `Filter` implementing `IFilter` interface and change it's `filter` method at runtime ?

Would be bad coding something like:

```
interface IFilter {
    filter(FilteringFunction): boolean
}
```

Or i need to create a specific `FilterByPrice`, `FilterByAge` class for every `IFilter` implementation i would like to have in my GUI?

I cited Strategy pattern because I read it can be useful to change algorithm at runtime. Can it be used to tackle this problem?
What i wouldn't like is to create dozens of `FilterInSomeWay` class for every GUI filtering component.
Thank you.

Comment: please don't **[cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is frowned upon...'")**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66262419/modify-method-behavior-at-runtime "Cross-posting is frowned upon as it leads to fragmented answers splattered all over the network..."

Comment: ok, i deleted duplicate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Choosing the right Design Pattern](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/227868/choosing-the-right-design-pattern)

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau thank you. It partially answers my question in the sense that I asked something like: "How to fit factory or strategy into this code". The real answer has to do with dirty code and a way to clean it through those patterns. Now i try to reformulate.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau please check update

Answer (score 0):

After better introspection this was easily solved with Strategy pattern.

```
IFilterGui {
    makeFilter(someParams) : IFilteringStrategy
```

```
Filter {
    constructor(filterStrategy : IFilteringStrategy)
    filter(node) { 
         this.filterStrategy.filter(node)
    }
}
```

Concrete example:

```
TimeFilterGUI implements IFilterGUI {
    setStartTime()
    setEndTime()
    makeFilter() {
        return new FilterByTimeStrategy(this.startTime, this.endTime)
    }

}
```

```
FilterByTimeStrategy implements IFilteringStrategy {
    constructor(startTime, endTime)
    filter(node) {
        if (node.startTime >= startTime && node.endTime <= endTime) keep else discard
    }
}
```